# Can't Join Computer to a Domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

We have two domain controllers PDC (Primary Domain Controller) and BDC (Backup/Additional Domain Controller) with DHCP roleinstalled and configured as fail-over between these two servers. The DHCP distribute IPs to clients all over the LAN (IP, Subnetmask, Default Gateway, DNS1: PDC IP, DNS2: BDC IP). The problem is that I can't join any clients to the domain unless I enter the DNS IP for the two servers manually! Although the DHCP is configured to distribute the DNS1 and DNS2 and when I check the IP configuration of the client computer I can see that the DNS1 and DNS2 are assigned via DHCP.

I can't figure this out! Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks...

Comment: `The problem is that I can't join any clients to the domain unless I enter the DNS IP for the two servers manually!` - Exactly what happens? What messages do you get?

Comment: When I try to join a client machine by typing the domain DC in the domain filed, It says that it didn't find a DC with that name over the LAN.!

Comment: 1. Turn off (stop and disable) Windows Firewall service on both DNS servers. Try again

2. This can be a DNS resolution issue. Try using just one (your primary) DNS server. If this doesn't work, open (edit) hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) and add your DNS IP and DNS server name. Save the changes and try to join your client again. Please post the results.

Comment: Windows Firewall Services is disables in both servers.

I'll try to remove the additional domain controller from the DHCP scope options and check to see if that works.

I want to add, that I have tested the forward and reverse lookup and it is working fine,

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the following commands:

nslookup dc1name.yourdomain.local
nslookup dc2name.yourdomain.local

ping -a ip.address.of.dc1
ping -a ip.address.of.dc2

These will make sure that DNS is functioning correctly on that system.

> When I try to join a client machine by typing the domain DC in the domain filed

Why are you typing in the name of the Domain Controller? Shouldn't you be just typing in the domain prefix? Just for clarity.

Comment: C:\>nslookup PDC.mne.gov
Server:  pdc.mne.gov
Address:  172.23.101.249

Name:    PDC.mne.gov
Address:  172.23.101.249


C:\>nslookup BDC.mne.gov
Server:  pdc.mne.gov
Address:  172.23.101.249

Name:    BDC.mne.gov
Address:  172.23.101.248

Comment: C:\>ping -a 172.23.101.249

Pinging pdc.mne.gov [172.23.101.249] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.23.101.249: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.23.101.249: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.23.101.249: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.23.101.249: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 172.23.101.249:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: C:\>ping -a 172.23.101.248

Pinging bdc.mne.gov [172.23.101.248] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.23.101.248: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.23.101.248: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.23.101.248: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.23.101.248: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 172.23.101.248:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms